# Chrome DevTools Protocol addScriptToEvaluateOnNewDocument using ruby chrome_remote

Tags: ruby, chrome-devtools-protocol

So I am trying to inject a script to run on any page using `addScriptToEvaluateOnNewDocument` on chrome 79, but it doesn't seem to be working.

I am using the ruby gem chrome_remote, which gives a pretty basic access to the CDP.

Here is an example ruby:

```ruby
scpt =<<EOF
    window.THIS_WAS_SET = 1
EOF

ChromeRemote.client.send_cmd 'Page.addScriptToEvaluateOnNewDocument',{source: scpt}
ChromeRemote.client.send_cmd "Page.navigate", url: "http://localhost:4567/test"
```

I then start chrome with `--remote-debugging-port=9222`

The `Page.addScriptToEvaluateOnNewDocument` will always return `{"identifier"=>"1"}` (even if I call it multiple times, say with different scripts).

And when I open console on the opened tab in Chrome (which works, so I know CDP in general is working), and check the value of `window.THIS_WAS_SET`, it is undefined.

Is there any way to verify the command was sent to the browser, such as a log in the browser it was received?  Any way to see what scripts were injected?  Why does each call always return a `ScriptIdentifier` of 1, that seems problematic?

Anyone have a similar example working?

Comment: BTW, I am not using the headless flag or mode, this is a full browser just being remote controlled.  I did try it with and without the additional `--enable-automation` flag and it made no difference to the behavior above.

Answer (score 6):

you should call "page.enable" first.

Comment: When you leave an answer it is good practice to make sure that the solution is easily understood. It would be helpful with an example that includes your answer along with an explanation.